# How can I limit the number of records included in an association within a response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am sending back a json object in the following way:

```
respond_with @authors, include: :posts
```

I need to limit the number of `posts`. I tried with:

```
respond_with @authors, include: :posts, limit: 10
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

What I'd do here is create a relationship for `latest_posts`:

```
class Author
  has_many :latest_posts, -> { limit(10) }, class_name: Post
end

# usage

respond_with @authors, include: :latest_posts
```